# Was the Taiping Rebellion the deadliest war of the 19th Century?

Tags: war, 19th-century, china

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiping_Rebellion#Death_toll):

> With no reliable census at the time, estimates are necessarily based
>   on projections, but the most widely cited sources put the total number
>   of deaths during the 15 years of the rebellion at about 20–30 million
>   civilians and soldiers. Most of the deaths were attributed to
>   plague and famine.

Comment: Nope, it was the War of Jenkins Ear which was biggest, although many of the deaths in that war went unreported.

Comment: @TylerDurden: The *War of Jenkins Ear* was fought 1739-1748, well before the start of the *19th Century*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_Jenkins'_Ear

Comment: What about its repercussions, though?

Comment: Voting to close for being trivial since apparently a [wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_and_anthropogenic_disasters_by_death_toll) easily answers this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Wikipedia maintains a list of "[Wars and Anthropogenic Disasters by Death Toll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_and_anthropogenic_disasters_by_death_toll)." Here are the 19th century entries, with lower and upper estimates for death toll.

1. Taiping Rebellion (20-100 million)
2. Napoleonic Wars (3.5-7 million)
3. Shaka's Conquests (1.5-2 million)
4. Du Wenxiu Rebellion (0.8-1 million)
5. American Civil War (0.67-0.85 million)
6. Circassian Genocide (0.4-0.5 million)
7. Paraguayan War (0.3-1.2 million)

The lowest estimate for the Taiping Rebellion is far higher than the upper estimate for any other 19th century conflict. Of course, it is not surprising that the largest anthropogenic disaster of the 19th century occurred in Asia when one considers that Asia was much more populous than the rest of the world combined:

[image]

([source](http://www.thuto.org/ubh/ub/h202/wpop1.htm))